# Replacing part of a string SQL based on condition

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a use case in amazon redshift which I have a list of numbers in a column:
E.g:
`1,2,3,4,5,6`
For this use case, the numbers have to be in the same column.
Lets say that I want to pass a parameter and remove that number from the list. The thing I try to do is:

```
IF FIRST ENTRY THEN
update table set number = replace(number,'{0},','') where 
username = '{1}';
ELSE
update table set number = replace(number,',{0}','') where 
username = '{1}';
END IF;
```

So basically I try to remove the number from the list. The problem is removing the first number since there is no comma before that number. How can I remove the number+comma if it is the first entry and remove comma+number for all the other entries?

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I see I forgot to include that sorry for that. I'm using amazon redshift which builds on postgresql

Comment: Redshift doesn't have a type called "list".  Are you trying to say that you are storing numbers in a delimited string?  That is just wrong.  You should fix the data model.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, Yes. And I do not think the data model is incorrect. We will use the table to enable row-level security in aws quicksight. Quicksight expects the data in this format so that is why a choice has been made to model the case like this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/restrict-access-to-a-data-set-using-row-level-security.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could append a ',' at the start and end of the string and then replace occurances of "{0},"

After that replace any trailing or leading commas...

eg:

```
--First append a ',' to the start and end of the column "number". 
update table 
   set number = replace(concat(',',number,','),'{0},','') 
 where username = '{1}';

--Replace any leading or trailing commas...
update table 
   set number = btrim(number,',') 
 where username = '{1}';
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks